Powershell script working in ISE, but not working in Azure Runbook
I have a powershell script as follows:
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add('ApiKey','xxx')
$file = 'xxx.zip'
Invoke-WebRequest "https://myurl/Export/" -Headers $headers -Outfile $file

This works perfectly on my local PC, but when I run it in an Azure runbook I get:
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
Could it be the version of Powershell that is the issue, or any other ideas?
Have run it locally from a cmd prompt using Powershell -file and it works.  Running it in the Azure runbook does not work.

You may have a cookie on local machine that allow code to work but do not have the cookie on remote machine.  I suspect if you delete the cookies on the local machine it also will not work.  Best way of getting working is to use Postman.  First try on working machine.  Postman has a control panel where you can view the entire request including headers.  Postman will automatically add missing headers.  Check the control panel and what headers are being sent.  Then repeat with non working machine and check headers.  The solution is to add missing headers to your code.

It works fine in Postman.  I re-created the azure runbook using Powershell V7.1 and the process works.  It doesn't work in version 7.2.  Must be some syntax that is deprecated.

It is probably default headers being added to the request in v7.1 that is not being added in v7.2.  Check the control panel in Postman and get all the HTTP headers.  Then add the missing headers to your PS request.  Also check the HTTP version in Postman if it is 1.0 or 1.1.  I believe PS is now using HTTP 1.1.

Any inner exception? (Use: Get-Error). Long shot, try: [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 (or a lower version).

Hi @JeremyReynolds, You can try with PowerShell V5.1 In runbook.


Powershell script working in ISE, but not working in Azure Runbook

There are multiple reasons for the error 400 Bad Request in an Automation Account.
Make sure to check that the PowerShell version in the Azure runbook is compatible with the script and also verify network restrictions
Here is an updated PowerShell script to capture more details about the request and response.
    $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
    
    Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" -Port 443
    $headers = @{}
    $headers.Add('ApiKey', 'test-api-key') 
    $file = 'test-response.json'
    $url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    Write-Output "Headers: $($headers | Out-String)"
    try {
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $headers -OutFile $file -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output "Response: $($response | Out-String)"
    } catch {
        Write-Output "Error: $_"
        if ($_.Exception.Response) {
            $responseStream = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream())
            $responseBody = $responseStream.ReadToEnd()
            Write-Output "Response Body: $responseBody"
        }
    }

Output:

Note: In my case, I have used a public URL and sample data with runtime version 5.1.


If there is any issue in the script, it will catch the error and display it as shown below

